# anonymous inner class issue in Java

Tags: android

May I ask why we have to use anonymous inner class in this case but not the conventional way?

```
@Override
public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add(R.string.external_url);
    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
            String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));     
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });         
    return super.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: You can make a MenuIntemClickListener object and override the onMenuItemclick and then set it to the MenuItem.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: What would be the "conventional way" that does not work in your example?

Answer (score 0):

```
MenuItemClickListener listener = new MenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
        String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));     
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
}); 
item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: nope, if you implement to the activity you would have item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it this way, it just tends to be more compact and succinct this way. If you want, you could do this:

```
@Override
public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add(R.string.external_url);
    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(menuClickListener);         
    return super.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private MenuItemClickListener menuClickListener = new MenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
        String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));     
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is still an anonymous class, I've only moved its declaration and assigned it to a private member variable. This might be useful if you want to set it on multiple items.

If you don't want it to be anonymous, you can make an inner class:

```
@Override
public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add(R.string.external_url);
    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuClickListener());         
    return super.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private class MyMenuClickListener implements MenuItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
        String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));     
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally, you could just let your Activity/Fragment implement the `MenuItemClickListener`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MenuItemClickListener {

    /* ... */

    @Override
    public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.add(R.string.external_url);
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);         
        return super.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
        String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));     
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
}
```